# Docker compose returns error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, docker-compose

I am trying to create a MySQL container inside Jenkins pipeline using Docker Compose . I run the following command after
installing docker compose version `1.9.0`

```
docker-compose -f ./jenkins/docker-compose.yml run -rm redis
```

and my compose file looks like

```
version: '2.1'
services:
   redis:
     image: "redis:alpine"
```

When running this I am getting the error as follows :

```
docker-compose $'\342\200\223f' ./jenkins/docker-compose.yml run $'\342\200\223rm' redis

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 62, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 93, in dispatch
  File "compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 31, in parse
  File "compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 42, in get_handler
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

docker-compose returned -1
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: I think you mixed up docker run and docker-compose command.

Comment: Try this docker-compose -f ./jenkins/docker-compose.yml up

Comment: @HareshChhelana getting the same error

Comment: try to use `version: '2'`maybe docker-compose 1.9.0 does not support configuration version 2.1

Comment: docker-compose 1.21.0 recognize your config properly

Comment: @BukharovSergey I am running this on `CentOS 6`. So `1.21.0` shows an error related with `GLIBC_2.14`

Comment: the `file -i` command returns following `docker-compose.yml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy and paste your Jenkins config by chance? `\342\200\223` is the octal representation of an "en dash" which is being used in places where you want a hyphen. Try adjusting your Jenkins config to use hyphens instead.